# Sorting list items by the numbers inside

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort list items which includes letters and numbers, e.g.

```cs
  var cities = new List<string>() 
        { 
           "London 4",
           "Berlin 6",
           "Paris 2",
           "Washington DC 3",
           "Roma 7",
           "Istanbul 5" 
        };
```

Sorting method will return to us:

```
Roma 7 
Berlin 6 
Istanbul 5 
London 4 
Washington DC 3 
Paris 2
```

Comment: are the items strings? do you have an object for it?

Comment: You're going to need to process the strings, split out the numbers, and convert them to integers to properly sort them.

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: I send a text from TextBox to ListBox. For each word, if the word is a new word, I add it to ListBox as a new item like this: "word 1". 

And if I sent that word to ListBox before, it becomes "word 2".

I want to sort the words by these counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why don't you use linq? something like

```
var cities = new List<string>() { "London 4", "Berlin 6", "Paris 2", "Roma 7", "Istanbul 5" };

var orderedCities = cities.OrderByDescending(c => int.Parce(c.Substring(c.LastIndexOf(" ")));
```

Comment: You need to convert to int, otherwise it will use string ordering.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(new[]
{
   "London 4",
   "Berlin 6", 
   "Paris 2",
   "Roma 7",
   "Istanbul 5"
});

var result = strings.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Split()[1]));
```

Comment: I don't understand how either fred_ or my answers don't answer your question.  Both of our answers are functionally equivalent and do what you seem to be saying.  What are we missing?